# Документация (summary) во внешнем файле

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, документация, intellisense

Имеется библиотека. В ней методы, поля (свойства), которые хорошо бы описать, чтобы при использовании Visual Studio высвечивала описание и подсказки для того или иного поля/метода.

Я знаю, что можно писать `<summary>` прямо в коде и в свойствах сборки добавить галочку для создания XML-документации.

Но если я сейчас прямо в коде начну писать описание, то код заметно удлинится. Можно ли как-то в отдельном файле написать эту документацию?

Чтобы в коде не было `<summary>`, но *IntelliSense* смог отображать эту информацию?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Да, это возможно. Используйте тег [include](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9h8dy30z.aspx).
Теперь достаточно

1. Аннотировать нужный метод так:

   ```
   /// <include file='external_summary.xml' path='docs/method[@name="MethodName"]/*' />
   public void MethodName(string arg)
   {
   }
   ```
2. Создать файл `external_summary.xml`, имеющий такую структуру:

> ```
> <docs>
>     <method name="MethodName">
>         <summary>Описание метода</summary>
>         <param name="arg">Описание параметра arg</param>
>     </method>
> </docs>
> ```

В результате после компиляции сборки с опцией `/doc` вы получите следующую xml-документацию:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doc>
    <assembly>
        <name>Application</name>
    </assembly>
    <members>
        <member name="M:Application.Program.MethodName(System.String)">
            <summary>Описание метода</summary>
            <param name="arg">Описание параметра arg</param>
        </member>
    </members>
</doc>
```

Comment: `Аннотировать нужный метод` - то есть подобную строчку надо писать над каждый методом и полем, которому требуется описание?

Comment: @Mr.Modest да, именно так: над каждым определением типа, интерфейса, метода или свойства, которые нуждаются в документировании. В любом случае ваш код заметно сократится.

Comment: спасибо, буду пробовать)

Comment: а как описать аргументы метода?

Comment: @Mr.Modest `<param name="arg">arg summary</param>`

Comment: не совсем понятно как это целиком должно выглядеть.. можете отредактировать свой пример с учётом параметров?

Comment: @Mr.Modest сделано

Comment: спасибо.. и ещё вопрос: как лучше описывать перегруженные методы и конструкторы?

Comment: @Mr.Modest можете для удобства записывать описания конструкторов в другой секции (например в `docs/ctors`). Перегрузкам просто задавайте другое имя в аннотации (эти названия будут преобразованы в конечном xml-файле) , а также добавьте необходимые параметры в тегах <param></param>

Comment: спасибо, вроде работает.. только вот не понял пока как элементы перечисления описать (enum)?

Comment: вариант как с методами типо добавить `<param name="name">` не канает тут, видимо =(

Comment: @Mr.Modest у элементов перечисления не может быть параметров, поэтому и соответствующий тег недоступен. Используйте внутри файла тег summary. Описание енумов и их элементов не отличается от описания методов в подключаемом вами файле:                                                
http://pastebin.com/ESw9AbAL

Comment: И перед каждым элементом enum'а также надо ставить include?

Comment: @Mr.Modest да, потому что в выходном xml-файле поля енума тоже считаются отдельными member'ами: http://pastebin.com/1ynFb5xu

Comment: Ясно, спасибо. Эх, а ведь этого хотелось избежать в первую очередь. Одна строчка теперь в 10 превратится, а то и больше :(